# Expect script to download newest file from remote server with grep

Tags: shell, grep, expect

I have an `expect` script to download the lastest database backup from a remote server. I am new to shell/expect scripting and I am struggeling with storing a clean filename from the output buffer in a variable. Here is what I got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set dbname [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh "sshuser@remote_ip"
expect "password: "
send "MySSHPass\r"
expect "$ "
send "cd /var/backup/dumps\r"
expect "$ "
send "ls -tl | grep --color=never -o -m1 \"\\<$dbname.*\\>\"\r"

expect "\r" # flushing the previous output from the buffer done right?
expect ".gz"
# the resulting string seems to have a leading newline or return char
set filename $expect_out(buffer)
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"

spawn sftp "sshuser@remote_ip"
expect "password:"
send "MySSHPass\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd database_dumps\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get /var/backup/dumps/$filename\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\r"
```

The extracted filename seems to have a leading newline or return char, so the sftp get path is not concatenated right... Any advice how to do this right?

Comment: Can you, please, edit your post with the output you get ? I have a doubt regarding the `\r` you use. Usually, in Unix/Linux world, `\n` is used...

Comment: @binarym Yes, you were right, I replaced all `\r` with `\n` and now it works!

Comment: @binarym Running `expect -d` as suggested by glenn jackman showed that lines in fact are terminated by `\r\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point, you don't need to `grep` the output of `ls`: this should suffice

```
send "ls -1t $dbname.*\r"
```

And to grab just the newest one:

```
send "ls -1t $dbname.* | head -1\r"
```

Now to the point of your question: yes it can be a hassle extracting the command output from the expect_out buffer. Do this:

```
expect -re {(.*)\r\n$ $}
set cmd_output $expect_out(1,string)
```

`cmd_output` will contain the shell command you sent, plus the output, all lines separated by `\r\n`. You can inspect it with

```
exec od -c <<$expect_out(buffer)
```

You need to remove the first `\r\n` separated line. Here's one way to do that:

```
if {![regexp {^.+?\r\n(.*)$} $cmd_output -> filename]} {
    error "unexpected output: does not contain \\r\\n"
}
# now, go get $filename
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful hints, but the line `set cmd_output $expect_out(1,string)` outputs `can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array...` for me, even though the `ls` call has found a file. So I suppose there is something wrong with the curly braces part. If I change it to maybe `expect -re "(.*)\n"`, $expect_out(1,string) contains the sent command

Comment: My regex is looking for everything before your prompt. I'd suggest running with `expect -d` and it will show you clues about why the pattern didn't match

Comment: That did the trick for me, with `#!/usr/bin/expect -d` I was able to adjust the regular expression to `{\r\n(.*)\r\n}` and now it works. BTW, what mean the curly braces in this context? Are they just a different way to delimit a string?

Comment: Yes. Refer to https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm rule number 6